# What is causing the curling and brown spot on my Philodendron Congo Green?

Tags: houseplants, plant-recommendations, diseases, plant-care

I just purchased this plant last Sunday. I repotted it and watered it the same day. Since then the leaves have begun to curl and one of the leaves is developing a large brown spot. The temperature in my apartment ranges from 72-80 degrees. What's causing this issue and how do I fix it?

[image: The Plant]
[image: Leaf]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like shipping damage, either the plant got too cold or too hot.  Remove the leaf and carry on...

Edit:  could be too much sun light.  You would have to wait and see as that usually develops into a dry paper thin area of the leaf.  The plant looks healthy so you could wait and see or take it back for a refund.

If it is fungal/viral/bacterial you will usually see it as small spots rather than the large area of damaged tissue that you see.

Comment: I bought it from a local nursery and brought it back myself.  Could it possibly be too much direct sunlight -- a form of sunburn? I noticed that there's also a large brown mark developing on the other leaf closest to the window behind the new unfurling leaf.  I'm facing northeast and get direct light from about 4-7pm.

Comment: I'll wait a few days to see what happens to the brown area.  I've rotated the plant so that the damaged leaves are away from the window and shifted the whole plant back a few feet.
Thanks for helping out!

Comment: @Chris the brown area is dead tissue, so don't expect it to go back to green.  It's bad aesthetically, but not really a drain on the plant. Cutting it off will improve the appearance, and promote new growth.

Comment: That's a shame; it's the biggest leaf on the plant, which doesn't have many as you can see.  Where should I cut it?  From the base?

Comment: Yes, take a clean razor or xacto knife and cut at the base close to the stem

Comment: I'd use bottled/distilled water, NOT tap water.  Too much salt.  Allow the soil to dry before watering again.  Drain that saucer.

Comment: @stormy  A plant that has been freshly brought is not going to be affected in the short term by tap water.  It takes some time, years, for soluble salt levels to build up in a soil less mix.

Comment: Ok. Will do. Thanks again for all the help guys.